# How to get checkbox value in text box were the no of text are about 40 & how to store them in database using mysqul database;

Tags: mysql, input

I am making a ticket booking website i want to show the selected seats in textbox which is readonly there are about 40 checkbox as seats 
`    
      1U
      7U
      13U
      19U
      25U

```
  <tr>
  <td id='s'><input name='2U' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='2U' />2U</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='8U' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='8U' />8U</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='14U' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='14U' />14U</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='20U' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='20U' />20U</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='26U' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='26U' />26U</td></tr>

  <tr><td id='s'><input name='3L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='3L' />3L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='9L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='9L' />9L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='15L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='15L' />15L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='21L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='21L' />21L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='27L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='27L' />27L</td></tr>

  <tr><td id='s'><input name='4L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='4L' />4L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='10L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='10L' />10L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='16L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='16L' />16L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='22L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='22L' />22L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='28L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='28L' />28L</td></tr>

  <tr><td>Passage</td></tr>

  <tr><td id='s'><input name='5L' type='checkbox' class='seat' value='5L' />5L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='11L' type='checkbox' value='11L' />11L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='17L' type='checkbox' value='17L' />17L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='23L' type='checkbox' value='23L' />23L</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='29L' type='checkbox' value='29L' />29L</td></tr>

  <tr><td id='s'><input name='6U' type='checkbox' value='6U' />6U</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='12U' type='checkbox' value='12U' />12U</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='18U' type='checkbox' value='18U' />18U</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='24U' type='checkbox' value='24U' />24U</td>
  <td id='s'><input name='30U' type='checkbox' value='30U' />30U</td></tr>
  </table></div>`
```

here are the check box and i want to store the value of checkbox which are selected or checked to `Seats : <input id='seats' type='text'  maxlength='10' size='10' readonly/>`
this textbox this is for bus ticket booking

Answer (score 0):

the best way (imho) is to use different table for selected seats, which references the main table (whichever one you use - maybe table for booking orders?)

like

```
create table orders( -- that's your actual table
  id integer primary key;
-- skip...
);

create table seats(
   seat_name   varchar(16), -- 12U, 30U etc etc
   order_id integer references orders(id)
);
```

the syntax maybe a bit different (i now use postgres, can't remember differences with mysql though), but you should get the idea. the code then can request all seat with order with something like

```
select order.*, concat(seats.seat_name) 
from orders join seats on seats.order_id = orders.id
where ... -- etc etc
group by seats.order_id
```

(maybe concat() is not the right one, btw, there should be other func, select better one)

or just request all for the current order like

```
select seat_name from seats where order_id = ?
```